# Setting contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, contact-form

I am setting a contact form. But it doesn't work. I got an error message like

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: contacts.name may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "contacts" ("content", "created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

.

It seems like this error comes from controller setting because I get this error message before the form shows. I mean I couldn't see any form on static_pages/contact.
 Could you give me some advice?

☆static_pages_controller

```
 def contact
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
  if @contact.save
    ContactMailer.sent(@contact).deliver
    redirect_to :action => :contact, :notice => 'お問い合わせありがとうございました。'
  else
    render :action => :contact, :alert => 'お問い合わせに不備があります。'
  end
end
```

☆contact.html.erb

```
<h1>お問い合わせフォーム</h1>

<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contact from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.string_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.string_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

☆routes.rb

```
 get "static_pages/contact"
  post"static_pages/contact"
```

☆contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :content
end
```

☆contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def sent(contact)
    @contact = contact

    mail(:to => "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", :subject => 'TsundokuBuster発お問い合わせ')
  end
end
```

Comment: first thing when you try to access this page it will try to create contact record as your get and post method mapped the same action **contact** and you are having  params[:contact] as nil at that time. This is the main cause of error . checkout if there is any . validation on database level. for showing the contact form you  have to call it through other other action such as new and render your page there.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I set the validations and got a new error. undefined method `contact' for #<Contact:0x007fdf2bbde798>

Comment: the action which render the contact.html should have @contact = Contact.new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in routes:

```
get "static_pages/contact"
post "static_pages/contact"
```

when you are accessing contact page you are calling a post request that normally sends empty values for name ant other attributes.

I'd remove the `post "static_pages/contact"` line and leave the form to use create action when hitting the submit.

```
 def contact
  @contact = Contact.new
 end
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
  if @contact.save
    ContactMailer.sent(@contact).deliver
    redirect_to :action => @contact, :notice => 'お問い合わせありがとうございました。'
  else
    render :action => 'new' :alert => 'お問い合わせに不備があります。'
  end
end
```

add add `resources :contacts, :except => [:show]` to routes.rb

Comment: Thank you very much!! I followed you instruction but got an error like NoMethodError at /static_pages/contact
undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdf2c237dd8>:0x007fdf2f5eaf18>.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43315/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-20630438-setting-contact-form

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. rmagnum2002. But I got thisNoMethodError at /contacts
undefined method `contact' for #<Contact:0x007fdf2be3e088> at contacts_controller

Comment: @contact
=> #<Contact id: nil, name: "荒牧さん", email: "goodman@gmail.com", content: "とどきますかー？？", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: @shema 
t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false

Maybe this is the cause of the error.

Comment: can you join this chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43315/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-20630438-setting-contact-form , also see my edits in the controller.